# NoSQL and Analytics

Tags: nosql, analytics

I am starting to build an application that is likely to demand scaling, so I am seriously considering NoSQL.  One thing that holds me back from perusing NoSQL is the availability of the data I store in it for analytics.  One of the major benefits of my application is going to be trending (age, location, etc).  Since I have not been able to fully shift my mentality from relational to NoSQL, I'm not sure if I'm just looking at the problem wrong, or if there really is a need for relational data to be available via live, ad-hoc querying.

Please set me straight!

Comment: Here you are: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2F-DItXtZs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

opting for a NoSql solution should be considered when you know that the relational db will break or hard to work with:
Usually it comes to this with two main reasons:

1. Data volume. When talking about volume we are talking about 500TB at least
2. unstructured data or dynamic schema demands

The horizontal scalability is just a result of the NoSql engine (automatic sharing)

If you have no any of these reason you can just manage with rdbms + sharding.
Analytics are possible on rdbms system too. 
NoSql are not ready yet to replace RDBMS, but very powerful in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran across InfiniDB, which puts a MySQL front end on a MapReduce-based back end specifically for analytics. Scales horizontally and vertically, and they claim it's extremely fast. Have a look at www.calpont.com for details on InfiniDB.

Answer (score 0):

> if there really is a need for relational data to be available via live, ad-hoc querying.

It depends on your use case. If you are looking at trends that look at say, a rolling 90 day average, then the past 6 hours of data might not make a difference. But if your application is trying to implement dynamic pricing for ecommerce, then you *will* want something up to the second.